# IE8 Compatibility mode | Type mismatch | detachEvent

Tags: javascript

DOX.js

```
function DOX_(win, doc){
    var that = this;
    this.events = {};
    this.onload = function(func){
        var prev_onload = win.onload;
        this.addEvent(win, doc, 'load',
            function(win_, event_){
                if(prev_onload)
                    prev_onload();
                func(win_);
                that.removeEvent(win_,event_);
            }
        );
    }
    this.addEvent = function(win, doc, event_, func){
        if(win.addEventListener || doc.addEventListener){
            var compat_event = win.addEventListener || doc.addEventListener;
            if(event_ in this.events){
                compat_event(event_, function(){
                    func(win, event_);
                    this.events[event_](win, event_);
                }, true);
            }else{
                compat_event(event_, function(){
                    func(win, event_);
                }, true);
            }
            this.events[event_] = func;
        }else if(win.attachEvent || doc.attachEvent){
            var compat_event = win.attachEvent || doc.attachEvent;
            var ie_event = 'on' + event_;
            if(ie_event in this.events){
                compat_event(ie_event, function(){
                    func(win, ie_event);
                    this.events[ie_event](win, ie_event);
                });
            }else{
                compat_event(ie_event, function(){
                    func(win, ie_event);
                });
            }
            this.events[ie_event] = func;
        }
    }
    this.removeEvent = function(win, doc, event_){
        if(win.removeEventListener || doc.removeEventListener){
            var compat_event = win.removeEventListener || doc.removeEventListener;
            compat_event(event_, this.events[event_], true);
            this.events[event_] = null;
            delete this.events[event_];
        }else if(win.detachEvent || doc.detachEvent){
            var compat_event = win.detachEvent || doc.detachEvent;
            var ie_event = 'on' + event_;
            compat_event(ie_event, this.events[ie_event]);//type mismatch error
            this.events[event_] = null;
            delete this.events[ie_event];
        }
    }
}
```

initialization:

```
var DOX = new DOX_(window, document);
DOX.onload(function(){
    alert("hello world");
});
```

I am creating a cross-browser compatibility framework for:

- IE7+
- FireFox 38+
- Chrome 43+
- Netscape 7+
- Opera 30+
- Safari 5.1.7+

IE8 Compatibility mode (IE7) error:

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729) Timestamp: Wed, 12 Aug 2015 16:41:11 UTC

```
Message: Type mismatch.

Line: 68
Char: 4
Code: 0
URI: http://nportal.rrh.com/JS/DOX.js
```

Comment: Try `console.log(typeof(compat_event));` before the line with the mismatch error. What does it log?

Comment: From some testing, IE gives the "type mismatch" error when any of the parameters to `attachEvent` are `undefined`. So `this.events[ie_event]` must be undefined for some reason.

Comment: Thank you, the issue was ie_event was returning onundefined. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to IE7 documentation attachEvent fires an exception "type mismatch" when one or more parameters are undefined.

`this.events[ie_event]` returns undefined.

-Credits to Nallar